# Avoiding dual employment via loss-of-pay payment

Tags: resignation, work-experience, india, notice-period

To give a perspective of my problems - **I started my career as a fresher engineer in October 2013** in a Global IT giant in India (Company-A) but due to location issues, on **14th of January 2014** I sent out an email (and also sent my ID card via secure courier) to my supervisor and left the job (i.e. I stopped going to work). I had signed a contract during joining to pay them a bond money of 75000 INR (if I quit my job within a year). I did not pay this money, as a result I never got an experience letter or relieving letter from Company-A.

I started a new job in my hometown (again as a fresher) from **15th January 2014** with another IT company (Company-B). **During the month of January 2014, I received salary from both Company-A and Company-B.**

I worked at Company-B with distinction till **30th March 2019**. I applied for resignation from Company-B, followed **all proper procedure, served the notice period and joined in Company-C from 1st April 2019**. Now, my present employer (Company-C) is unaware that I have worked in Company-A, since I chose to hide my employment at Company-A from both Company-B and Company-C.

Few days back, I got a call from the recruitment team of Company-A, asking if I wanted to join for an open position. I told them that I have absconded from Company-A many years back, they told me that as per the data in their system, my status in the portal is marked as "Normal Exit" and not "Absconded". And I was free to join back in Company-A, as a result I had one round of technical interview and one hr interview, I performed well in both rounds.

Now I got a call from the recruitment team of Company-A saying, they need my relieving letter/ experience letter during my first tenure (the tenure being - October 2013 to 25th February 2014 - YES, as per the system data of Company-A, my last working day is 25th February), to initiate the LOI. I told them that I did not have it, so they advised me to pay old my dues, after which they will give me the experience letter for October 2013 to February 2014. Now this experience letter will be a problem for me since it shows an overlap in my employment (i.e. a case of dual employment during the month of January 2014 to February 2014). As per Company-A records my total dues now are - 95000INR (75000INR for bond + 20000INR for the salary of January 2014, which is being shown as loss of pay).

Now my question is, can I ask the people at Company-A to give me an experience letter till December 2013 or 14th January 2014? Anyways I will be paying back the money, so technically I am returning the money for the period I have not worked. And an experience letter till December 2013 or 14th January 2014 will fix my timeline, effectively managing my dual employment problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with Glen here.

You will be better off if you don't accept the offer from A and politely let them know that you've already joined C.

I don't think they would be ready to reduce your employment duration(even if you pay the salary for that period) as that would be too much of a correction in their databases.

Have you considered other parameters like the pay scale, work culture, employee satisfaction and technologies you will be working on?

Even after everything being good, joining A would mean that you have absconded from effectively 2 firms. You are also burning bridges with C here. In A too, this(leaving just after 4 months from your first job) might be a bad remark on your profile while you are considered for any promotion down the line.

Comment: thanks.. i was having second thoughts, thanks a bunch for helping me make the choice..

Answer (score 3):

I would not even have considered accepting a position at the firm you left. Don't bother continuing with the process, tell them politely that you're no longer interested in the position.

The reason for this is that you open yourself up to too many risks here that you don't need if you just go work elsewhere.